# Folding over list to create another list

Tags: haskell

As a beginner Haskell programmer, I've been finding that do the following a lot

```hs
let states = foldl processLine [start_state] (lines input)
```

The result from these kinds of expressions are usually 1-to-1 (or a-couple-to-1) mapped to each line of input, but the the `processLine` function requires looking back 1 or 2 states to compute the future state

Is there a better way to do this? It feels weird to use `fold` while I'm generating a list.

Comment: Without knowing what `processLine` does, nobody can say whether there's a simpler way to accomplish the same thing. But a function like [`mapAccumL`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) might be useful for doing something that's "almost `map`, but with a little state".

Comment: Remember, a foldl only knows the state you pass to it and the current element in the list. Picking that state is key. If it needs to be aware of _other list elements_ you have to pass those along as part of that state.

Comment: This is tricky, and is going to depend pretty significantly on how _exactly_ the states and lines are dependent.  Does it need `mapAccumL`?  `scanl`?  Something entirely custom that pattern-matches?  It'll depend.

Comment: Thanks amalloy and Louis Wasserman! Those look useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state you pass to a fold is critical because it's the only way a fold "knows" anything other than the current element in the list. If you wanted to address the previous two elements in a list, you might write something like the following.

```
data Previous a = NoPrevious | PreviousOne a | PreviousTwo a a 
  deriving Show

reverse $ snd $ foldl (\(p, acc) x -> case p of { NoPrevious -> (PreviousOne x, []); PreviousOne a -> (PreviousTwo a x, []); PreviousTwo a b -> (PreviousTwo b x, [a,b]:acc) }) (NoPrevious, []) [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Where the result is:

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
```

Should you wish to generalize this for any number of previous elements, you might write something like the following. (*Disclaimer: Not optimized at all.*)

```
foldlPrevN n f init lst = foldlPrevN' n 0 [] f init lst
  where
    foldlPrevN' _ _ _ _ init [] = init
    foldlPrevN' n n' prev f init (x:xs)
      | n' < n    = foldlPrevN' n (n' + 1) (prev ++ [x]) f init xs
      | otherwise = foldlPrevN' n n (tail prev ++ [x]) f (f init prev x) xs
```

```
Prelude> reverse $ foldlPrevN 3 (\i p x -> (p, x) : i) [] [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[([1,2,3],4),([2,3,4],5),([3,4,5],6)]
Prelude> reverse $ foldlPrevN 4 (\i p x -> (p, x) : i) [] [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[([1,2,3,4],5),([2,3,4,5],6)]
Prelude> reverse $ foldlPrevN 4 (\i p x -> (sum p + x) : i) [] [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[15,20]
```